# Find child elements by missing attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Finding elements by attribute in jQuery is simple:

```
$(parentElement).find('[attribute]');
```

How do you find elements, that **don't** have a certain attribute?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's why the [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) is made for.

Try,

```
$(parentElement).find(':not([attribute])');
```

Comment: or, $(parentElement).find('[attribute]').not([attribute]);

Comment: Rajaprabhu is right. See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HXT3s/). <div> <a target="_blank">Active</a> <a>Inactive</a> </div> <script> $('div :not([target="_blank"])').css('font-weight', 'bold'); </script>

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:not` although `filter` is most likely faster:

```
$(parentElement).filter(function() {
    return !$(this).attr('attribute');
});
```